# Laplace Green function on $R \times S^3$

Tags: field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, classical-field-theory

On flat Euclidean $R^4$ the Laplace operator has the Green function $G(x,y) = \frac{1}{4\pi^2(x-y)^2}$, i.e.

$$-\Delta G(x,y) = \delta^4(x-y).$$

What would be the corresponding Green function on $R \times S^3$? I'm guessing this must be simple because $R \times S^3$ is probably conformally equivalent to $R^4$ (just like $S^4$ is) but not sure how to do the conformal transformation on $G(x,y)$.

Comment: I think this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-009-0826-0 could help.